# How to receive broadcast packet on 0.0.0.0?

Tags: java, sockets, broadcast, dhcp, datagram

I need some help for my Java app. I need to receive broadcast packets on a Datagram Socket bound to a wildcard address. The most important thing is that my wlan0 shouldn't have a configured IP address because the goal of this app is to retrieve a valid IP from a server, kind of a DHCP.
First I configure the wlan0 on 0.0.0.0.
Moreover I setup the default routing to go through the wlan0 interface (the only interface up).
Ifconfig output is:

```
lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:117 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:117 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:9337 (9.3 KB)  TX bytes:9337 (9.3 KB)


wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:77:dd:e7:a4  
      inet6 addr: fe80::21b:77ff:fedd:e7a4/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:30211 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:6128 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:16654450 (16.6 MB)  TX bytes:654646 (654.6 KB)
```

This is how I create socket on my Client:

```
InetSocketAddress broadcast = new InetSocketAddress("0.0.0.0",listenPort);
socket = new DatagramSocket(null);
socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
socket.setBroadcast(true);
socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(broadcast.getPort()));
```

Then I send datagram packets from client to 255.255.255.255. The server (on the same subnet) receives them and answers with a broadcast on the subnet. The client machine receives server's broadcast packet but the socket does not and it blocks itself on socket.receive();

Is there a way to receive datagrams on a socket bound to a not configured (no IP) interface?

I tried giving an IP to wlan0 and all works but I need to have the wlan0 not configured, only bound to the 0.0.0.0 wildcard address.

Comment: You are using the same socket to send and receive on, right?

Comment: could it cause problems? should i receive on a different socket?

Comment: No, keep the same socket.  It will be harder to use two.

Answer (score 0):

Surely that bind() throws an IOExceotion, as the socket is already bound when constructed?

Change new DatagramSocket(null) to new DatagramSocket(broadcast); remove the bind() call; and change the first argument of new InetSocketAddress() from '0.0.0.0' to null.

Comment: no exception is thrown. I did the changes you suggested but nothing changed. The packet arrives but the socket doesnt get it. If i configure wlan0 with an IP address everything works, if i configure it on wildcard address 0.0.0.0 it doesnt work. It seems it is not possible to receive broadcasts on wildcard address bound socket..is it true? any solution?

Comment: @EJP new DatagramSocket(null) prevents it from binding to an address. What you're referring to is when new DatagramSocket() (the default non-parameterized constructor) is used - that binds it to a system allocated port.

Answer (score 0):

Do the "bind" call before calling "setBroadcast" and "setSoTimeout"

Comment: nothing changed. I check if SO_BROADCAST is enabled and it is. I dont think it's a binding problem. I looked around and it seems that its not possible in java to receive broadcast packets on a socket bound to a wildcard address, on a non configured interface. Is it true? do you know any solution?